# Making web apps non crawlable

Tags: angularjs

This question might seem a little dump but we are building an app that has important data atleast for us and we cant afford , these data crawled by any site (google or any other). How can I do that ??? I was relying on angular and how do I acheive the same in Angular .

Thanks ::!!

Comment: Well, make sure only authenticated users can access the data.

Comment: I cant bring an authentication to the app , But I want it non-crawlable.

Comment: Why put a non-protected app on the web if you don't want it to be usable? Keep it for yourself, behind your firewall. If you want to protect about well-behaving robots, then use a robots.txt. But most robots can't crawl single-page apps relying on JavaScript anyway.

Comment: This seems like a paradox. You want to make the data publicly available, but you don't want someone to copy or access it on a large scale. In the long term, you can't have it both ways; authentication is your only option if you want to hide the data. Perhaps Google can't crawl an SPA _now_, but if the data is valuable enough, someone can always create a custom robot for scraping your site.

Answer (score 0):

Many SPA-developers are trying to solve opposed problem, so you can just do nothing at this moment, if you build SPA. But I hope soon Google will learn how to index SPA, and I believe your only 100% solution is authentication.